# I missed the removal step after my upgrade from Oneiric to Precise

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, package-management, uninstall

I have just upgraded my ubuntu form Oneiric to Precise. But unfortunately my PC hanged up, just before I was to start the removal step to remove the unnecessary packages.

Hence, after a restart my PC is working well but keeping the old and unnecessary packages is wasting my limited PC resources.

Please help me how to identify and remove them?

regards,

Answer (score 1):

Try running this command in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

That should remove unnecessary packages.